# Is it possible to use an enum inside a generic interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I do have an enum like

```
public enum VALUES{
    VALUE_1,
    VALUE_2
}
```

I do want to define a generic interface like (maybe)

```
public interface Listener<T extends Enum<VALUES>>{
     public doSomething(Object data);
}
```

And a subscriber like:

```
new Subscriber implements Listener<VALUES.VALUE_1>{
    ...//DO SOMETHING
}
```

so that I can determine via reflection the type used for the generic interface. 
As I will have a lot listeners and I do not want to call every listerner, i want to determine the type of Message they are listening to.

How can I achieve something like that? Yeah I know that this does not work. I can't clearly say that it is however even possible... But I want a suggestion how to solve this.

Comment: A few comments: `VALUES` should really be `Values`, it would be `T extends Values` and `Listener<Values.VALUE_1>` doesn't make sense: `VALUE_1` is a constant, not a type.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Whatever you’re trying to do, this is the wrong way to do it.  Why do you need each Listener to be aware of the type to which it’s listening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference only types in generics eg: `Integer`, `String` but not values like `1` or `"string"`. The same counts for enums. You can only pass the type of the enum (in your case `VALUES`) but not the direct value (`VALUE_1`)

So only following is valid for your case:

```
public interface Listener<T extends Enum<T>> {
    void doSomething(Object data);
}
```

Comment: Yeah but this is not a suggestion how to solve the problem of mine. I do know that an Instance like VALUE_1 is not possible. I am searching for something like ineritage of enumeration, or a static constant definition for messages types

Comment: @Code.IT can you then specify for what exactly you are using that value? it is an interface which does (and should) not specify an implementation, so that value is clearly useless

Comment: Its like I already said, the interface does not contain any more code as I posted. Its just a generic interface which is used to subscribe to an eventbus. on the eventbus thread I want to get the generic type or something like that defining the type the value of the message has and if the message will be posted to the subscriber.

Comment: Then the interface doesn't need the generic anyway. because it is not used in the interface itself. An implementer has no benefit of passing a type to the interface. as it is just not used